# Show more than four digits in year citation

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have been trying to obtain Harsanyi (1967-68), but what I got is Harsanyi (7 68) which is last 4 digits of year item in bibliography except ''-''. Here is my MWP and bibitem, thanks for any help in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{harsanyi67,
    title = {Games with Incomplete Information Played by Bayesian Players,{Parts I,II,III}},
    author = {John C. Harsanyi},
    year = {1967-68},
    journal = {Management Science},
    volume = {14},
    pages = {159--182, 320--334, 486--502},
}

\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{harsanyi67}  

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that it will help, but could you try `year = {{1967-68}}`?

Comment: @MWc: I have tried already didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to modify the `apalike.bst` bibliography style to be less picky about year labels. Make a copy of the `.bst` file and give it another name. Here I've used `apalike-hyphen-year.bst`.  In the `.bst` file you will find the following function:

```
FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.label                       % apalike ignores organization
        'author.key.label                       % for labeling and sorting
      if$
    }
  if$
  ", "                                                  % these three lines are
  *                                                     % for apalike, which
  year field.or.null purify #-1 #4 substring$           % uses all 4 digits
  *
  'label :=
}
```

Replace the line

```
 year field.or.null purify #-1 #4 substring$           % uses all 4 digits
```

with the following:

```
year field.or.null  #-1 #8 substring$    % modified to allow arbitrary years up to 8 chars
```

Save the file. This will allow your odd year reference to work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{harsanyi67,
    title = {Games with Incomplete Information Played by Bayesian Players,{Parts I,II,III}},
    author = {John C. Harsanyi},
    year = {1967-68},
    journal = {Management Science},
    volume = {14},
    pages = {159--182, 320--334, 486--502},
}

\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citep{harsanyi67}

\citet{harsanyi67}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-hyphen-year}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Nit-pick.  I believe the two years should be separated by an en-dash rather than a hyphen.  Not sure whether it should be "adjusted" by the `.bst` or by the input.

Comment: @barbarabeeton This most certainly should not be accommodated by the `.bst`; since the `.bst` change is a bit of a hack, really, and has no understanding of the content of the label.  Possibly `biblatex` can solve this in a more principled way.

Answer (score 0):

As per design you will get name of the author and four digit year only when you use apalike style. So you have to use year = four digit number and not 1967-68. If you use two years you will get author name and 7 68 only.

Comment: This is a valid observation. But there should be an alternative to include '1967-68' in the citation.