# Write "this volume" in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

I'm writing a book chapter and want to cross reference other chapters in the same book. The desired citation is: (Author, this volume).

However, when I use `year={this volume}` in BibTeX (with natbib / apalike) the outcome is (Author, lume) because a year is expected. How can I get my desired output?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using `natbib` and the style is `apalike`.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example and the desired output. Do you have a bibtex item for your own book? It is very strange and unusual to use bibtex to cross-reference. Normally such things would be done with something like varioref.

Comment: I added a minimal working example. The book is not "my" book. It's an edited volume with many chapters written by different authors. Thus, it should appear like a regular citation, just with "this volume" instead of the year.

Comment: Are entries of interest of type `@incollection` (or `@inproceedings`?), and hence to they share the same editor(s)? Please advise.

Comment: Since you use the `natbib` citation package, you could write `(\citeauthor{xxx}, this volume)` to generate the desired look of the citation call-out. No need to fiddle with the bst file or do anything special with the entry's `year` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to write (\citeauthor{xxx}, this volume) as recommended by @mico.

Another solution would be to follow the approach described in: [Show more than four digits in year citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298973/show-more-than-four-digits-in-year-citation)

To copy apalike.bst and change the entry `year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$` in the copy to:

```
year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #14 substring$
```

Comment: For copyright/copyleft reasons, one should *never* edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly. At the very least, please make a copy of the file, give the copy a new name, and then edit the newly-named copy.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can edit your answer to say that you should make a new copy in your local TeX tree or project folder, and edit that, if you like.

Comment: @Mico Even assuming no legal concerns, I’d always want to make a copy of any files I needed to change to compile my document, so I could archive them and compile the document on another installation. I wouldn’t want to have to change `apacite.bst` again, or ask a colleague to. Also, that changes the behavior of any other document source I might happen to have that uses `apacite`.